# Can i benefit from PowerApps to create a submit form inside our modern web page

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, modern-experience, modern-pages, powerapp

I am working on sharepoint online site. and i added a new modern page which represents our finance department. where users can access the department's News, Events, Documents, etc..
now i want inside the modern page to add a feedback form, which allow users to specify their names (not necessary a real People or Group field) and their feedback, something as follow:-

[image]

and after submitting the form to show a message for the users, something as  "your feedback was submitted" without forcing any redirection inside the modern page.

Now to achieve this i am planning to do these steps, but not sure if i am at the correct path:-

1. I will create a custom list. then i will add the Name & Feedback fields to it. (i think this step is required).
2. Create a PowerApps cusotm form, and embed this PowerApps form inside our modern page using the Microsoft PowerApps modern web part.
   [image]

now i am not sure if PowerApps can be used to implement our requirement? now my main issues are:-

- Can we force the PowerApps form to show a message for the users once submitted? and to prevent any redirection?.
- also usually i use PowerApps to create a full app for a list, but i am not sure if i can create a form similar to the one i showed in my above image, where this form should not show any additional components (such as the built-in search field, additional links and button), and it should only show 2 HTML fields + submit button. so this is possible using PowerApps??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a power app containing form and whatever number of fields you want to specify , there are also lots of other elements that you can put on your app one of them is screen that you can use to show success message etc after form submit , mentioning the steps in brief here :

```
1.Create an App from blank from https://web.powerapps.com.  
2.In the default screen 1 , go to insert tab and add form .  
3.Also create one more screen(success) , Insert-> Screen and put some text there e.g confirmation message  
4.Select data source as your list and include the fields/data cards that you want to display   
5.Insert a button and onselect write code for submitting form and navigate to success screen.  
6.Go to your modern page and in power app web part insert app url in the property pane .
```

You will see your custom form and it will behave like you mentioned.

You can explore different elements in powerapp creation  wizard and eventually you will see that you can achieve any custom form/redirection logic etc.

Comment: now i followed your steps and i was able to create a PowerApp and embed it inside our modern page using the PowerApp.. i tested the PowerApp using internal user accounts the the users were able to submit the form, but when i tried to submit the form using an external user (who is already accessing the site collection and have contribute permission on the site and on the source list), the external user could not see the embed PowerApp. now i read that PowerApp can not be used/shared by external users? is this correct?

Comment: Please mark it as Answer if it helped with your original issue , for using powerapp for external user you can create a seperate issue with respective tag to get reply from other community members using power app, here are few things that you should cross check , external user has permission to add data to target list, user has power app in the office license, page is published after you embed power app.

Comment: @SharePointTestDev Please don't add multiple questions in comments/questions, if you have further questions it would be great to add it to a new question, don't forget to upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted!

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP I already up-vote Ashutosh answer as it was helpful for.. but i want to wait for some days maybe i will get other ideas, mainly due to external users limitations when using PowerApps..

Comment: @Mohamed El-Qassas MVP but i did not get why my question was put on hold, it is not too board i am asking about building a feedback form using PowerApp..

Comment: @SharePointTestDev First, Please avoid asking multiple questions at once. See the How to [Ask page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Second, you didn't mention in your main question the external user's issue, and as your comment, the Ashutosh answer helped you to solve your original issue!! So you should appreciate his time and effort and accept his answer to close this question, then add a new question with your new issue?

Comment: Please be specific, don't ask multiple questions, the volunteers here try to help us for free by providing advice and help for a specific and clear issue, and forgive me, they are not here to build your feedback form!! that is actually too broad!

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP but if it is too board, then how i got an answer on this + 38 veiws without being tagged as too board.. and i do not feel that it is too board + i am not asking to build my feedback for.. if you read my question in details , you will see that i am asking specific question about PowerApps,, and i gave the feedback form as an example only.. my question is about if i can return a message after adding the item through PowerApp + if i can only show 2 fields inside the powerapp... which was answered already by Ashutosh..

Comment: @SharePointTestDev The point mentioned above is correct , that's how the guidelines are for questions in community. i see no issue if you create a issue mentioning about the user access issue or any other issue in power app forms and refer this thread in your issue if reqd, New Question will have specific tags and have more visibility to community and for sure you will get quick response ,  chances of people coming and reading through comments of already answered questions are rare.Cheers!

Comment: It's the same concept if 5 members from the 38 views vote to reopen it we will open it automatically?! As a moderator, I see it's a too board for the above-mentioned reasons! additionally, you asked two questions not one (1. can return a message after adding the item through PowerApp and 2.can only show 2 fields inside the powerapp ) ! moreover, you added a new issue in comments!!

Comment: @SharePointTestDev BTW, Who said, "I am asking about building a feedback form using PowerApp" ? Who adds another issue in the comments? plus you said Ashutosh answered your question so why you don't respect his answer and accept it and ask your new issue in sperate question! Please respect the community rules and moderators decision! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP ok fine... but can you stop using an offensive approach ... like using  "who said" ... "who adds" . we are here to help each other,and not to point on each other. i do know that it is preferred to ask a single question.. but also asking 2 related questions will not break the community rules.. i think the community rules as against asking 2 separate questions on the same post,, but there should not be any problem if i break a question into multiple sub-questions which are talking about a single issue inside the same post... Have a nice day also :)